# Popup window external link

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

For some time I have been using http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ Modal for showing modal popup, I have found out that I can load external url (templateURL) to this view. But the problem is that loading takes about 3-4 seconds.

I need to load external content to modal popup and I can't find any fast/well working way.

Popup is on Edit/Create button thats why loading content before pressing button is not good for me(would take forever to load 100-200records in iframes or so)

How can i reduce load time for angular bootstrap modal?
Or maybe there is other way I could load my MVC view in modal?(I'm using mvc5 razor)

Example of my code:

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="height:50px; width:100px;" ng-click="open('new_tp')">Create</button>  
<p>
<div id="butplace"></div>
</p>                      
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
```

And new_tp:

```
if (size == "new_tp") {
    modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '/Transport/Create/',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        size: size,
        resolve: {
            items: function () {
                return $scope.items;
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Does every item has it's own template? I don't really get `Popup is on Edit/Create button thats why loading content before pressing button is not good for me(would take forever to load 100-200records in iframes or so)` why would you load everything in iframes?

Comment: I mentioned iframes, because I have found way to use Jquery widget ui modal, but it does not loads external, it loads iframes. And does that when website starts, then when u hit button it just shows it in modal.

Comment: Every item has same template, but i pass id to template and then information there changes (so information in template is different).

I gave example for create, but still create is very slow (sometimes up to 8seconds load first time and 2-4 seconds later)

Comment: I see, well if the template is same then it's cached, no problem here
so the only reason might be a slow model resolving, is your resolve containing all items or just the one you want to edit?

Comment: It contains a lot of information, but when I load it not in popup it loads fast. Model is a form with about 30 items. Maybe rendering that takes so much time?

Comment: Please isolate the problem into plunker, that will speed up resolving your issue :)

Comment: Loading empty view takes time to (~3-4seconds). I'll try plunker.

Comment: Just how can I put my View in plunker..?

Comment: You can add files on left if necessary

Comment: Ya. But I don't think MVC will work on Plunker :D

Comment: No it works just fine, the view works on a iframe with preview (you can open it in another tab if you want - take a look at iframe src)

Comment: `templateUrl: '/Transport/Create/',` is it angularjs view? it should be single file containing partials for best performance

Comment: /Transport/Create/ is because I reach that page for generating create view...