# MVC Razor open modal view in another view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

What is the most simple and fastest way to open a View as modal(popup) in other View?

I have Index view with button Create/Edit. When i press button i want to open a Create.cshtml or Edit.cshml Views as modal/popup, fill information, save and reload to Index View.

I have tried angular-bootstrap script to load external templateurl, but that is too slow for me (somewhy it takes up to 10s).

Is there some tool or way to do that fast and simple?

Thank you.

Comment: If it takes 10 seconds to load a page then it sounds like there's a different problem to be addressed first. Why does it take so long?  Essentially you have a couple of options: 1) Include the "modal" view as a partial view in the parent view and style it to be hidden, using JavaScript to display it. 2) Include a placeholder for the "modal" view in the parent view, again styling it to be hidden, and use AJAX to get the rendered partial view when using JavaScript to display it. But if it takes 10 seconds to render the view then it's still going to take 10 seconds no matter where/when you do it.

Comment: If I load it without that script it goes fast (only that scrip somehow renders all views(yes, even empty ones) slow.

Problem is with that script somehow...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Popup window external link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530632/popup-window-external-link)

Comment: I'm asking here about other ways than my done one. Why is this duplicate?

Comment: If you make a server call then offcourse it will take some time to load the page in your modal. If you really want a quicker one then i will suggest to load the partial view in your modal DIV at the same time your form loads. And later just show the DIV container in modal. You have to take care of clearing the form each time it triggers. Let me know if you like the idea, i will show you how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function newTask() {

          var myModal = $('#myModal');
          $.get('/Cloud_Customer_Events/Create/' + id, function (data) {
              $('#mydiv2').html(data);
              $('#myModal .modal-header .modal-title').html('Create Record');
              $('#myModal').appendTo("body").modal('show');
          });

      }
```

Also, check the javascript files that are loading in your partial view for redundancy...